# Custom conditional redirections after WooCommerce checkout payment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I use Lirox One theme on Wordpress with WooCommerce. I want make custom redirections after payment:
If a customer buy product ID 333, It will be redirected to product 444 (for example).

I have make some custom code but it doesn't works, I get an error 500 (and debug is empty).

What I am doing wrong and how can I make it work?

This is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'check_order_product_id', 1 );
function check_order_product_id( $order_id ){
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
       $product_id = $item['product_id'];

          //* single product id
          if ( $product_id == 399 ) {
            // Content Title line
            $url = 'http://yoursite.com/custom-url1';
            }
          if ( $product_id == 358 ) {
            $url = 'http://yoursite.com/custom-url2';
          }
          if ( $product_id == 398 ) {
            $url = 'http://yoursite.com/custom-url3';
          }

          if ( $product_id == 357) {
            $url = 'http://yoursite.com/custom-url5';
          }

          if ( $product_id == 356) {
            $url = 'http://yoursite.com/custom-url6';
          }

          if ( $product_id == 335) {
            $url = 'http://yoursite.com/custom-url';
          }
          if ( $order->status != 'failed' ) {
    wp_redirect($url);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Don't get the reason of the `foreach`loop... after the first run of the loop you'll redirect anyway, so the loop won't ever be executed a second time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For redirections, use a custom function hooked in WordPress **`template_redirect`** action hook, 
to avoid errors 500…

I have changed your code as you will see, to match your requirements. This code is made for WooCommerce version 3+:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'conditional_redirection_after_payment');
function conditional_redirection_after_payment(){
    // When "thankyou" order-received page is reached …
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {
        global $wp;

        // Get the order ID from the browser url
        $order_id =  intval( str_replace( 'checkout/order-received/', '', $wp->request ) );

        // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        // If the order status is 'failed' we stop the function
        if( $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) return;

        // HERE set in the array for each product ID the coresponding url final path
        $product_id_url_paths = array(
            '399' => '/custom-url1',
            '358' => '/custom-url2',
            '398' => '/custom-url3',
            '357' => '/custom-url4',
            '356' => '/custom-url5',
            '335' => '/custom-url6',
        );

        // Iterating through each order items
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values ){
            // The Product ID
            $product_id = $item_values->get_product_id();

            foreach( $product_id_url_paths as $key_id => $url_path ){
                if( $key_id == $product_id ){
                    // Product is found and ID match: we got our path url. We redirect
                    wp_redirect( home_url( $url_path ) );
                    exit(); // always exit
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Code is tested and works on WC 3+

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  In your Code you have to remove the `exit` which you have used after the `wp_redirect`. Other all will work fine. Some more References are provided below in order to have better understanding of the Concept.

> **Explanation**: Then you Provide Redirect only for the Particular Product
>   ID alone not For all the Product IDS since it may lead you to the
>   Internal Server Error as it is in the Foreach Loop.

It is Fine using `wp_redirect()` for the redirection purpose.

It is correct what have you checked for the Product ID. The Thing is that you have to follow another method if the URL are to be explicitly passed.

```
// We don't know for sure whether this is a URL for this site,
// so we use wp_safe_redirect() to avoid an open redirect.
wp_safe_redirect( $url );

// We are trying to redirect to another site, using a hard-coded URL.
wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/some/page' );
```

**Some More Reference:**

```
<?php wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit; ?>

Redirects can also be external, and/or use a “Moved Permanently” code :

<?php wp_redirect( 'http://www.example-one.com', 301 ); exit; ?>

The code below redirects to the parent post URL which can be used to redirect attachment pages back to the parent.

<?php wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post->post_parent ) ); exit; ?>
```

**Reference:** https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/

Comment: I delete exit but 500 its still exists

Comment: That means your order status might not be received over there. Please have a confirmation over that

Comment: i have 500 on the whole site :D

Comment: Remove the Code what you have added and check the Site

Comment: without this this code its okey, and i dont have an any error, and log debug log its empty

Comment: Check whether the `foreach()` and the `function()` are closed proper after you add this code.

Comment: Yep i miss to }} in the end :D Thx mate :D

Comment: Sure. Thanks. Kindly consider my answer which made you way to solve the problem. Up vote or Accept it so that it might be useful for others who faces the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Th accepted answer works for Woocommerce 3+, for older versions (I'm using 2.6.4) it does not. For anyone else using this version, try the following code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'conditional_redirection_after_payment');
function conditional_redirection_after_payment(){
    // When "thankyou" order-received page is reached …
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {
        global $wp;

    $order_id =  intval( str_replace( 'checkout/order-received/', '', $wp->request ) );
    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // If the order status is 'failed' we stop the function
    if( $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) return;

    // HERE set in the array for each product ID the coresponding url final path
   $product_id_url_paths = array(
        '1234' => '/your-path/'
    );
    // Iterating through each order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item){
       // echo $item_id;
        // The Product ID
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];

        foreach( $product_id_url_paths as $key_id => $url_path ){
            if( $key_id == $product_id ){
                // Product is found and ID match: we got our path url. We redirect
                wp_redirect( home_url( $url_path ) );
                exit(); // always exit
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}